# Determine which subsets are linear subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to consider the following subsets of $R^3$ and determine which are linear
subspaces. I am not sure how I should approach this. These are the subsets:

1. The set of all vectors of the form $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ with $x_1, x_2, x_3 \in R$ and $x_1 - x_2 = 0$
2. The set of all vectors of the form $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ with $x_1, x_2, x_3 \in R$ and $x_1 - x_2 = 3$
3. The set of all vectors $x \in R^3$ which satisfy $u \cdot x=0$ where $u=(1,1,1)$
4. The set of all vectors $x \in R^3$ which satisfy $u \cdot x=3$ where $u=(1,1,1)$

So for it to be a subspace, then:

- $v ≠ Ø$
- If $x, y \in V$ then $x+y \in V$
- If $\lambda \in R, x \in V$ then $\lambda x \in V$

Would I be right in testing each subset against these points? Can someone help me out?

Comment: (2) and (4) are not (try finding a pair of elements whose sum is not in there), while (1) and (3) are subspaces (prove this)

Comment: For this type of question, good thing to check at first would be whether $0 \in$ in the set..If it is not, the set wouldn't be a subspace.

Comment: How would I check whether 0 is in the set? For (2) could I add $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ and $(y_1, y_2, y_3)$ then I can say that this is in V. So I can derive this to state that $x_1 - x_2 + y_1 - y_2 = 6$. Would this be proof that it is not in V?

Answer (score 0):

I will only prove the first one for you, the rest is the same processes.

**Proof**: Let $P$ be the set that all vectors of the form $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ with $x_1,x_2,x_3 ∈ R$ and $x_1 - x_2 = 0$. Set vectors ***u***:$<a,b,c>,~$  ***v***:$<d,e,f>∈ P$, then:

1.The zero vector of $R^3$ is in $P$

2.P is closed under vector addition.Because ***u,v*** $∈ p$, then
$$a - b = 0,$$ $$d - e = 0$$
$$=> u+v = <a+d,b+e,c+f>$$$$Satisfy~~~(a+d)-（b+e） = 0$$Hence ***u+v*** $∈ p$. That is for each $u$,$v$ in $P$, the sum of $u+v$ is in $P$.

3.P is closed under multiplication by scalars.Because ***u*** $∈ p$, then
$$a - b = 0,$$
$$=> cu = <ca,cb,cf>$$$$Satisfy~~~ca-cb = 0$$Hence ***cu*** $∈ p$. That is for each $u$ in $P$ and each scalar $c$, the vector ***cu*** is in $P$.

Hence, $P$ is a subspace of $R^3$